# Eclipse : How can we put Break points inside jar file?

Tags: eclipse

We are using Eclipse Helios as our IDE .
We have a class in form of a jar file .

Our code will pass throught that class file ,due to some reason we are getting NullPOinteException ,

can we put break points in that Jar file ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like the accepted answer at this URL covers this pretty well: [How to set a breakpoint in Eclipse in a third party library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370814/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-eclipse-in-a-third-party-library)

Of course, if it doesn't just give me a comment and I'll see what else I can dig up. :)