# How to set breakpoints in class files without the source in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

The class file is contained in a jar archive (which I don't have the source) and I can view that file like an ordinary Java file in Android Studio by the built-in de-compiler feature. I set breakpoints in that class file and started debugging but it didn't stop at the lines marked by breakpoints. Is there any way to do that?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse : How can we put Break points inside jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017857/eclipse-how-can-we-put-break-points-inside-jar-file)

Comment: @Rakesh The Eclipse solution doesn't apply to Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

There was an Android bug raised for the same. Please check if any of the solution works for you from following official developer.android bug tracker link

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81439