# Unable to download CrudRepository source in Eclipse IDE - Source Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Usually when I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click the `CRUDRepository` in the interface shown like below in Spring Tool Suite, the source automatically gets downloaded.

```
public interface StudentImpl extends CrudRepository<Student, Integer>
```

But when I am trying this thing on eclipse it doesn't work. It does work on my colleague's pc. How can I download source by just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click? Currently I am working on Spring Boot. I have added the preferences screenshot below:

RE @nhu: I have tried doing the same but it didn't download anything.

[image]

[image]

> Source not found  The JAR file
>   Z:\Users\ASharma20.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\2.0.6.RELEASE\spring-data-commons-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar
>   has no source attachment.
>
> You can attach the source by clicking Attach Source below:

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26672169/3728901

Comment: @DoNhuVy I have added screenshot above, It didn't worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes going to maven --> Download Sources doesn't work & never downloads the source.

For this we need additional step as shown below:

1. Delete the jar from .m2 folder for which you are trying to download source
2. Re-download the jar using maven --> Update Project --> force Update of snapshots

[image]

[image]

3. Now You can repeat same step (maven --> Download Sources). This time it will download the source !!

[image]