# How to debug code by stepping into jar file code for which I have the source code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: java, jar, vscode-debugger

I am a C#, c++ developer. If I have the code and pdbs to external dlls, I am able to step into the code of the external dll, by pointing IDE to the code and/or the PDBs. I want to do something similar with Java JARs

I have created a Micro Service framework in java using Visual Studio code. This compiles into a jar file. 
I have another application that is consuming this jar file. When I am debugging my application, how can I step into the code of the Micro Service jar?

I am using VS Code 1.45.1, zulu 14, maven 3.6.3

Say I have a jar file called MyMaths.jar, inside it there is a class mybasicmaths

```java
    public class MyBasicMaths{
       public int addNums(int a, int b) {
           return a+b;
       }
    }
```

This jar is being used by another application consuming the MyMaths.jar. I have resolved the dependencies using Maven. In the client application, I have code like

```java
    public class MyMathsConsumer {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
         int a = 10;
         int b = 20
         MyBasicMaths myObj = new myBasicMaths();
         int c = myObj.addNums(10, 20);
         System.out.println(c);
       }
    }
```

I am able to run my project fine. But I want to be able to stepinto the code of  MyBasicMaths.addNums() from MyMathsConsumer.

When I am debugging, I am able to step into amqp-client-5.7.3.jar and even zulu classes, but not into the jar file I have created.

Similar question has been asked for eclipse 
[Attach the Source in Eclipse of a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180411/attach-the-source-in-eclipse-of-a-jar/26672169)

I am asking the same for Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You need to put more details like your code, different ways you have tried but couldn't get the solution. This will help others to better answer your question. Do have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Lazycoder_007 hope the question is clearer?

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: @EmmanuelF I switched to using IntelliJ. IntelliJ is able to stepinto my jars. But if you can attach you source, you may be able to step in, please check the link  https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/cookbook/attach-source-javadoc-artifacts.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(from https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project)

> By default, a referenced `{binary}.jar` will try to search
> `{binary}-sources.jar` under the same directory, and attach it as
> source if one match is found.
>
> If you want to manually specify a JAR file as a source attachment, you
> can provide a key-value map in the sources field:
>
> ```
> "java.project.referencedLibraries": {
>     "include": [
>         "library/**/*.jar",
>         "/home/username/lib/foo.jar"
>     ],
>     "exclude": [
>         "library/sources/**"
>     ],
>     "sources": {
>         "library/bar.jar": "library/sources/bar-src.jar"
>     }
> }
> ```