# How to write data in multiple cells in Excel using java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I wrote a code for writing data in an Excel sheet.In this i have to write the data in multiple cells.But it is showing some Errors.For one cell it is able to change the data.I kept **for loop** for changing the data in multiple cells.For this it is showing Error.
Can any one tell me that where i did mistake.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.lang.String;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import jxl.Cell;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Column;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFComment;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class Sele1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String FileName = "C:\\Users\\u304081\\Desktop\\Java\\new.xlsx";

        try 
        {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream3 = new FileInputStream(FileName);
            File outputsheetfile1 = new File(FileName);
            if(outputsheetfile1.exists()) 
            {
                System.out.println("File existed");
                try
                {
                    XSSFWorkbook ObjWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream3);
                    XSSFSheet DriverTableSheet = ObjWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
                    for(int i=1;i<3;i++)
                    {
                    XSSFRow row1 = DriverTableSheet.getRow(i);
                    XSSFCell Cell1 = row1.getCell(0);

                    System.out.println("Cell1"+ Cell1);
                    //System.out.println("Cell2"+ Cell2);
                     String str = "Abc";
                     Cell1.setCellValue(str);

                     FileOutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream (FileName,false);
                     ObjWorkBook.write(out1);
                     fileInputStream3.close();
                    }

                } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
    }
```

**Error I am getting is:**

```
ObjWorkBook.write(out1);

`"poi-bin-3.9-20121203\poi-3.9\poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar has no source attachment"`
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Course Pack Resolution Details");
        outputFileName = outPut.getAbsolutePath(); 
        int rownum = 0;`enter code here`
        for (int i = 0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {
            Object[] objArr = dataList.get(i);
            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);

            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                sheet.autoSizeColumn((short) cellnum);
                if (obj instanceof Date) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Double) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
                }
            }
        }
        if (outPut.exists()) {
            outPut.delete();
        }
        FileOutputStream out =
                new FileOutputStream(outPut);
        workbook.write(out);
```

DataList is ArrayList of Array Object so you can enter as much data as you want init.

Example of DataList:

```
dataList.add(new Object[]{"Sr No.", "Cols1", "cols2", "cols3"......."colsn"});
```

respective data you can insert in list. this example is for .xls format if you want .xlsx then use xssfworkbook.

May be help you.

Comment: Thank u i am trying to do the Same.But i am checking that one for particular cell in different rows.

Comment: Hi Umasri Can you told how exactly you doing??

Answer (score 0):

The error you mentioned:

```
ObjWorkBook.write(out1); Here it is showing Error as "poi-bin-3.9-20121203\poi-3.9\poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar has no source attachment"
```

Does not seem to be anyways related to the problem you mentioned about writing data in multiple cells to excel.

You may want to look at this:

[How can I link source to a jar package in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454590/jar-file-has-no-source-attachment-jar-file-includes-source-code)

Answer (score 0):

=======write data in excel-file in play framework===============

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample sheet");

Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
data.put("1", new Object[] {"empNo.", "name", "salary"});
data.put("2", new Object[] {1, "John", 1500000d});
data.put("3", new Object[] {2, "Sam", 800000d});
data.put("4", new Object[] {3, "Dean", 700000d});

Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
int rownum = 0;
for (String key : keyset) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
    int cellnum = 0;
    for (Object obj : objArr) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
        if(obj instanceof Integer) 
            cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
        else if(obj instanceof String)
            cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
        else if(obj instanceof Double)
            cell.setCellValue((Double)obj);
    }
}

try {
    //new excel file created by fileoutput stream object 
    FileOutputStream out = 
            new FileOutputStream(new File("/home/jagasan/workspace-playexcelApp/public/ExcelFile3.xlsx"));
    workbook.write(out);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("Excel written successfully..");

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return ok("file reading is completed");
```

=======read data from excel and store in database in playframework=======

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    /*
     * public Result index() { return
     * ok(index.render("Your new application is ready.")); }
     */
    public Result readExcel() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try{
           InputStream ExcelFileToRead = new FileInputStream("/home/jagasan/workspace-play/excelApp/public/ExcelFile3.xlsx");

            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(ExcelFileToRead); 
            HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
            HSSFRow row;
            HSSFCell cell;        
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            boolean flag=false;
            while (rows.hasNext())
            {
                row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
                if(flag==false)
                {
                    flag=true;
                    continue;
                }
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                ExcelFile excelfile=new ExcelFile();
                int i=0;
                while (cells.hasNext())
                {
                    cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    if(i==0)
                        excelfile.setEmpNo((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    if(i==1)
                        excelfile.setName(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    if(i==2)
                        excelfile.setSalary(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                   i++;

                }
                excelfile.save();

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("error");
        }
        return ok("successful");
    }
```

======in build.sbt=======

use the dependency jar file means apache API

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "3.8", "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "3.9"
)
```