# Cannot import Carrot2 to Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, carrot2

I want to use Carrot2 as a library to build a new software. But when I build a new project, there is no "create project from existing source".
Can I know how to use Carrot2 as a library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The option is now called **Use default location**, you need to uncheck it and provide your folder location there. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368903/where-is-create-project-from-existing-source-in-eclipse-indigo).