# Eclipse - How to open and set breakpoints in code attached to the target platform plugins?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I am a newbie to Eclipse. I have some plug-ins installed in my eclipse workbench along with their source plugins (thus i have attached code with these plugins).

How can I **open(and view)** the source code of these installed plugins and set break-points so that I could debug these plug-ins?

My motive behind this task is to get a deeper understanding of the source code of some of these plug-ins.

Though the post [How to set a breakpoint in Eclipse in a third party library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370814/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-eclipse-in-a-third-party-library) explains some methods, it doesn't tell how to open and view the attached source code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need breakpoints, use Ctrl-Shift-T (Open Type), enter the name of the class and set the breakpoints.

But if you really want to learn about the plugin in question, there is more: Open PDE perspective, there is a view "Plugins". Select the plugin you are interested in, choose **Import->As Source** from the context menu of the plugin. This imports the plugin into your workspace, so you can really investigate all artifacts inside, not only the source. By default, your launch configuration will use the plugins from the workspace as first choice, so you can even modify that imported plugin now and see the effects when running your workspace.