# Conditional breakpoint on an Eclipse internal plugin code ... in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin

I want to debug an Eclipse plugin that I'm writing with Eclipse. To debug this plugin I would like to set a conditional breakpoint on the Eclipse ClassLoader, which is a package of the Eclipse distribution: *org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.EquinoxClassLoader*, in the plugin *org.eclipse.osgi_X.YY.jar*.

So the question is: how can I do this ? Is it even possible ?

I saw some other questions to set conditional breakpoints; it's either on current project packages or third-party packages, but not on an internal plugin. Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F)

Comment: Yes, I believe it's not extactly what I want: this page describes how to debug one of your own project or any jar being a dependecy of your project. But in fact, I want to debug one of the Eclipse internal plugin, while running one of mine plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar problem has been solved in this post:
[Eclipse - How to open and set breakpoints in code attached to the target platform plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11092432/eclipse-how-to-open-and-set-breakpoints-in-code-attached-to-the-target-platfor?rq=1)

(if someone can mark this question as duplicated).