# check if the filter from referenced libraries is called succesfully or not

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a filter in one of the referenced libraries. I have configured this filter in web.xml of my application.

Consider I have the filter in `abcd.jar`.

I am configuring it to my web.xml as

```xml
<filter> 
    <filter-name>message</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.test.myfilter</filter-class>
    <init-param> 
      <param-name>message</param-name>
      <param-value>A message for you!</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
  </filter> 
  <filter-mapping> 
    <filter-name>message</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/test/filter2*</url-pattern> 
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>   
  </filter-mapping>
```

When browsed the url containing the match `localhost:8080/test/filter2.jsp`. I could access this correctly. But not sure whether my filter is called successfully or not.

I cannot test it by adding the print statements in the filter class because it is from referenced libraries.

Is there any other way to test it.

Comment: Is there a condition on which filter acts differently then normal? Like not logged-in or invalid number of parameters, etc.... use that condition to check if its working.

Comment: @HarryJoy. I think there is no such condition. Can I change the name of the parameter and check..

Comment: Then what does it filter? which kind of request does it filter? make a request that doesn't pass the filter condition.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @HarryJoy.This is the filter applied to soap based web service. It is adding some MimeHeaders to soap request.

Comment: @djaqeel. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Comment: @User222 Have you checked my answer? Did it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create method break-point in your third party jar file. And then wait to see if the break-point is triggered or not.

For [creating the break-point in third party library in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370814/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-eclipse-in-a-third-party-library), open the class file in your jar in project explorer, then open the outline, right click and add the break-point.