# How can I set breakpoint in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got this  error when trying to set a breakpoint in a library class (in a .class file)

[image]

The error says that i don't generate line number attributes, while in preferences i have them enabled Picture here

[image]
I've tried also re-downloading eclipse and reinstalling java, but nothing changed

Comment: can you check
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/957822/eclipse-unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes

Comment: did you try javap -verbose on the class file and  See if it actually has a line number?

Comment: https://solveme.wordpress.com/2008/08/27/unable-to-install-breakpoint-due-to-missing-line-number-attributes/

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how to do javap -verbose on a class that is in a jar file :(
Sebri, i've already that checks in my settings :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot debug `*.class` files. You may debug your own `*.java` files. Look at this helpful article: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html 

I think, It many helps you.

Comment: So basically i can't set a breakpoint in any imported library? :/ Good to know, thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @FrancescoJimi, Yeah, you can't debug imported library, but you can debug *.class files from your project.

Comment: @Francesco check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370814/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-eclipse-in-a-third-party-library

Comment: @FrancescoJimi, You may download 3nd party libs with source and without source. If you downloaded source, you may debug 3nd party libs.

Comment: unfortunately the only lib i can download is the compiled lib, the one with .class files :/ I guess i'll find out another way to test that class :) Thanks everyone for the quick answer :)