# Breakpoints in Eclipse for Lagom or Akka code

Tags: eclipse, scala, lagom, scalac

We are using Eclipse to remote debug Lagom and Akka applications, but Eclipse is not allowing us to put breakpoints in the code.

I am able to put breakpoints in my Scala code, but not in the Akka library.

For example: I am trying add a breakpoint on the second line:

```
  override def eventsByTag(tag: String, offset: Long, max: Long): Source[Try[(PersistentRepr, Set[String], JournalRow)], NotUsed] =
Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(queries.eventsByTag(s"%$tag%", offset, max).result))
  .via(serializer.deserializeFlow)
```

Comment: i tried checking out one of the scala project and compile it with -g flag on, then try to add breakpoint in eclipse . it is still not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370814/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-in-eclipse-in-a-third-party-library

Comment: It could happen if the class file(from jar) and the attached source code are different. Try setting breakpoint at different lines in the same file. If it works in other parts, then it's definitely a mismatch between class file & source.